# Rostopic new terminal

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, I am trying to learn ROS, and have just started.
After installing ROS Indigo and Gazebo7.
I tried running the turtlesim as given in the [ROS wiki tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics#Introducing_rostopic):

The tutorial says that in new terminal  run: rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key

When I open a new terminal window and run this command I get the error message rosrun: command not found

Am I missing something? What?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247904/rostopic-new-terminal/) by [azgard](https://answers.ros.org/users/28512/azgard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to source the setup.bash in your new terminal.

Sourcing the setup.bash for ROS only affects the terminal that you run it in, so you need to source the setup.bash for ROS in each new terminal (or add it to your bashrc).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azgard](https://answers.ros.org/users/28512/azgard/) on 2016-11-12**:
Thanks that was the issue

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-12**:
@azgard: could you please mark your question as *answered* by ticking the little checkmark icon to the left of @ahendrix's answer? That will clearly mark this question as resolved. Thanks.